# Exclude fields from printing in Twig

Tags: views, theming

I am overriding the fields `template views-view-fields--machine_name.html.twig`.

I want to render some Fields in a different div than the other fields. I do not want the fields to render twice.

```
<div class="foo">
  {{ fields.field_events_date_start.content }}
  {{ fields.field_events_date_start_1.content }}
</div>

{% for field in fields -%}
  {{ field.separator }}
  {%- if field.wrapper_element -%}
    <{{ field.wrapper_element }}{{ field.wrapper_attributes }}>
  {%- endif %}
  {%- if field.label -%}
    {%- if field.label_element -%}
      <{{ field.label_element }}{{ field.label_attributes }}>{{ field.label }}{{ field.label_suffix }}</{{ field.label_element }}>
    {%- else -%}
      {{ field.label }}{{ field.label_suffix }}
    {%- endif %}
  {%- endif %}
  {%- if field.element_type -%}
    <{{ field.element_type }}{{ field.element_attributes }}>{{ field.content }}</{{ field.element_type }}>
  {%- else -%}
    {{ field.content }}
  {%- endif %}
  {%- if field.wrapper_element -%}
    </{{ field.wrapper_element }}>
  {%- endif %}
{%- endfor %}
```

If I exclude those Fields from the display in Views it hides them both when they render before and in the normal content area.

```
{{ content|without('field_events_date_start', 'field_events_date_start_1') }}
```

...Does not work because I am rendering Fields, not content.

How do I get the fields to render before, but be excluded later?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would have to remove the two fields from `fields`.

```
<div class="foo">
  {{ fields.field_events_date_start.content }}
  {{ fields.field_events_date_start_1.content }}
</div>

{% for field in fields|without('field_events_date_start',  field_events_date_start_1') %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of this I did last week.

Filename `views-view-fields--view_name--display_id.html.twig` i.e. `views-view-fields--acquia-search--results.html.twig` in my case.

```
{{ fields.title.content }}
<p class="search-result__item-description">{{ fields.search_api_excerpt.content }}</p>
<ul class="search-result__item-meta">
  <li class="search-result__item-link"><span class="label">View More:</span> {{ fields.url.content }}</li>
  <li class="search-result__item-date"><span class="label">Date Modified:</span> {{ fields.changed.content }}</li>
</ul>
```

I am printing the fields at my discretion and providing my own markup.

If you install [Twig XDebug](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_xdebug), you can drop `{{ breakpoint() }}` into your template and see your variables.

Answer (score -2):

Example: in variable 'content' was 10 elements (name, date, id,...)
`{{ content }}` - get all fields
`{{ content|without('date') }}` get all fields(name, (((deleted - date))), id,...), except 'date'